# iup.GetParam in LUA: data validation in the callback function

Tags: validation, callback, lua, iup

LUA novice, experimenting with GUI using `iup.GetParam` using `LUA 5.1`.

I have a simple use of `iup.GetParam` (which works fine with a simple callback function testing for OK & Cancel) and am trying to add some simple data validation for the parameters (e.g. testing a parameter for being alphanumeric), but am unsure of the correct approach.

I've searched the reference manual (and for code examples), but drawn a blank so far.

1. Using the string validation example, if I want to reject the
   character entered by the user and display the old value of the
   parameter, do I simply `return 0` from the callback function, or, do
   I also have to reset the value of the parameter to its previous
   value before the return? Or is the right approach something
   completely different?
2. In either case, do I have to `refresh` / `update` the GUI display with a
   separate `iup` call, or does `GetParam` handle that for me?

Whatever combination I try, it doesn't appear to work (the parameter happily displays the non-alphanumerics). Debugging shows the validation test and return working as coded, so the advice I'm seeking is to get confirmation of the right approach. Sharing a simple working example would be great.

Comment: http://luanotlua.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. simply return 0
2. No, IUP will do everything for you, in this case

Download the "getparam.wlua" from the examples folder, then add to its callback this:

```
  elseif (param_index == 1) then
    return 0
```

You will notice that the integer value is now read-only.